# setting the default remote branch for git push

Tags: git

I have the following setting in my gitconfig:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

I set my upstream branch using:

```
git branch --set-upstream staging spci/master
```

But now I still have to do:

```
git push spci HEAD:master
```

If I want to push my branch to the `master` branch on my `spci` remote.

How can I configure git so that

```
git push
```

Is the same as

```
git push spci HEAD:master
```

I think I could do it using `git config push.default tracking` but this affects my other branches, and I just want this to happen for my staging branch.

Thanks

Comment: How about make it `tracking` and fix your other branches config? Or create an alias just for this branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
[remote "spci"]
  # Other remote configs ...
  push = HEAD:master
```

This is not optimal since it affects all pushes to this remote, but since I only use this remote as upstream remote in this branch, I guess it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `push.default` to `upstream` (or its deprecated synonym `tracking`).  Currently there is no way to set this option on a per-branch basis.